# select where index + other field

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, index-tuning

Learning indexing

I have made an index, consisting of usergroupid and birthdate

I understand that queries will then benefit from indexing when searching usergroupid and/or birthdate

But what happens if I throw in other fields in the query?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE usergroupid = 54 AND (birthdate BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '1983-01-01') AND cityid = 100
```

Will the extra `"AND cityid = 100"` mess up the indexing, or will it be seen as something to be found quickly AFTER handling the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra predicate wont mess up the indexing. Most likely your index will be evaluated first and any rows that are found will be evaluated against the predicate cityid = 100.

On the other hand, assuming your index is defined as (usergroupid, birthdate). If you remove usergroupid = 54 from your query, the index won't do any good and you will have to evaluate all rows in the table against:  `birthdate BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '1983-01-01') AND cityid = 100`

Comment: Ok got it. Do you think a PRIMARY key will be prioritized over any index? (search/speed wise)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A primary key is in all DBMS that I know of implemented via a unique index. Given a query the optimizer evaluates a number of ways to solve the task (access-plans), which indexes to is one such decision. The optimizer will then try to pick the access-plan that has the lowest cost.

Comment: Ok. Well, perhaps I'm overthinking this now. The part about indexes is enough for now, thanks